# Can a SSH server or client to initiate a unencrypted connection?

Tags: ssh

Several clarifying questions:

- Is it possible to disable the SSH encryption using options at the OpenSSH server/client or some appropriate hack?
- Is it possible to do this at the time of the transmission, of course with full control over the server?
- Are there known servers/clients (except OpenSSH), which allow you to do this?
- Are there any plugins for this software or patches for their code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253), both the client and server would have to accept `none` as a cipher type in order to establish a plaintext connection.  OpenSSH (and probably most SSH implementations) refuses to accept `none` as part of the Cipher configuration, so you would not be able to do this with OpenSSH without recompiling both the client and server to accept `none`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your client/server support it, the standard foresees this possibility by using *none* as the cipher ([source](https://support.ssh.com/manuals/server-admin/44/Ciphers_and_MACs.html)).

That would have to be setup prior to stabilishing the connection.